# Using the serverless framework, is it possible to have functions call each other locally? Similar to SAM's sam local start-lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm using serverless with AWS. I want to be able to test lambda functions calling other lambda functions locally. I noticed that there is a way to do this with the aws SAM tool (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html). Is there a way to do this with the serverless framework?

If not out of the box, would it be simple to implement? Does `serverless invoke local` use SAM under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it by myself but I found that there is a serverless plugin for it:

[serverless-offline-direct-lambda](https://github.com/civicteam/serverless-offline-direct-lambda).

Sounds like you may give it a try.

---

The complete list of the [serverless pluggins](https://github.com/serverless/plugins)